# which is more efficient in conditional looping?

Tags: c#, collections, foreach

suppose i have the following collection

```
IEnumerable<car> cars = new IEnumerable<car>();
```

now I need to loop on this collection.

I need to do some function depending on the car type; so I can do one of the following ways:
**Method A:**

```
       foreach( var item in cars){
           if(item.color == white){
              doSomething();
           }
           else{
              doSomeOtherThing();
           }

       }
```

or the other way:
**Method B:**

```
foreach( var item in cars.where(c=>c.color==white)){
   doSomething();
}

foreach( var item in cars.where(c=>c.color!=white)){
  doSomeOtherthing();
}
```

to me i think method A is better bec.  I loop only once on the collection
while method B seems enticing bec. the framework will loop and filter the collection for you.

So which method is better and faster ?

Comment: This is probably a case of premature optimization, but the first loop is generally faster, though not because it only loops once -- it will be faster because it doesn't allocate any memory and avoids extra function calls. (The second version has to allocate memory for two lambdas and probably two enumerators as well, plus invokes the lambda functions once for every item.) Faster still would be to have your data already split into two sets and do two tight loops over each. Failing that, having them ordered by colour would help too, because then the branch predictor can do a good job.

Comment: Brilliant name/avatar combo, by the way :-)

Comment: Are you under the impression that the LINQ extensions aren't performing a comparison?

Comment: Ed S. Im wondering if filtering using linq is faster than using if-else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends on how complicated the filtering process *is.* It may be so insanely efficient that it's irrelevant, especially in light of the fact that you're no longer having to do your *own* filtering with the `if` statement.

I'll say one thing: unless your collections are *massive,* it probably won't make enough of a difference to care. And, sometimes, it's better to optimise for readabilty rather than speed :-)

But, if you really want to know, you *measure!* Time the operations in your environment with suitable production-like test data. That's the only way to be certain.

Comment: Yet, to answer the question directly, I can't imagine any scenario in which B is equally or more efficient than A.

Comment: @EdS., probably not, but maybe they're indexed on color like a DBMS table, or held in white and non-white hash buckets :-) Unlikely but my advice still stands: measure, don't guess.

Comment: Haha, yeah, that's the kind of thing I was coming up with.

Comment: If it is an AsParallel the LINQ-Queries should be faster on a multicore system. But once again, it still depends on the data, and he has to measure. But i can easily think cases where a LINQ Query can be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Method A is more readable than method B. Just one question, is it car.color or item.color?